# Is there any Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE osgified version patch available?

Tags: spring, osgi

Is there any Spring 5.0.6.RELEASE osgified version patch available? We have to to do quick release so need to upgrade older spring but currently our framework uses OSGI based container, though spring has officially stopped supported OSGI. Is it possible to have patched version of latest Spring framework?

Though I know it's better to convert to Spring based container but since time doesn't allow I'm in search of any osgified version of Spring jars.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Servicemix produces osgified versions of a lot of well known libraries, Spring included: https://github.com/apache/servicemix-bundles

Currently the latest osgfied version of Spring is "5.0.5.RELEASE", with "5.0.6.RELEASE" probably due to come in the near future. Otherwise, getting servicemix pom.xml for 5.0.5.RELEASE and manually changing Spring version should work (from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6 there should be just internal implementation changes).